# wxpython GUI testing tool Inquiry

Tags: python, user-interface, testing, wxpython, wxwidgets

For a couple of days, I was trying to find appropriate GUI test tools for toolkits (wxwidgets). The program that am going to test is written in python.I have tried SQUISH but it did not work when using "Verification Point", meaning that object property values were not appearing in squish. The GUI testing tool doesn't have to be free or open source, as long as it meets the above requirements and that you have "first-hand" experience using the framework. I would really appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for tools like these:

- http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/
- https://github.com/ldtp/cobra
- http://sikuli.org/

wxPython also comes with [wx.UIActionSimulator](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.UIActionSimulator.html) which you could probably use for automated testing.

The squish framework doesn't work with wxwidgets, to my knowledge. It might work with PyQt though and possibly Tkinter